# Bookshelfjs destroy where and where

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

Is it safe to do this?

```
await MyModel.where(toSnakeCase(userID), user.id).
          where(toSnakeCase(shopId), user.shopId).destroy();
```

within bookshelf model. I would like to do a delete where matches two columns

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but if you still have the doubt you can use `orWhere` or `andWhere` in your case it will look like this:

> await MyModel.where(toSnakeCase(userID), user.id).
> andWhere(toSnakeCase(shopId), user.shopId).destroy();

Or you could also use a single where:

> await MyModel.where({ toSnakeCase(userID): user.id, toSnakeCase(shopId): user.shopId}.destroy();